# Get selected text from a form using wtforms SelectField

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

This is a question upon the use of `wtforms SelectField`.

Once the form submitted, I wish to extract selected text.

I have the following form:

```
from wtforms import Form, SelectField
class TestForm(Form):
     hour = SelectField(u'Hour', choices=[('1', '8am'), ('2', '10am') ])
```

Here's the view:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_create():
form =TestForm(request.form)
if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
    test = Test()
    form.populate_obj(test)
    test.hour=form.hour.name
    db.session.add(test)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('test_create'))
return render_template('test/edit.html', form=form)
```

With `test.hour=form.hour.name` I obtain the attribute `name` (no surprise...), whilst I need the text (let's say `8am` if the first option is chosen).

How should this be possible ? Thanks for any hint.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Define choices global in forms:

```
HOUR_CHOICES = [('1', '8am'), ('2', '10am')]

class TestForm(Form):
     hour = SelectField(u'Hour', choices=HOUR_CHOICES)
```

import it from forms, convert it to dict:

```
from .forms import HOUR_CHOICES

hour_display = dict(HOUR_CHOICES).get(form.hour.data)
```

Comment: It doesn't work if the key is an integer! Weird

Answer (score 7):

It was answered as a comment, so I'm writing here.

Use `form.hour.data` to get the value instead of the name.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the choice indexes, is much more simpler:

```
class TestForm(Form):
  hour = SelectField(u'Hour', choices=[('8am', '8am'), ('10am', '10am') ])
```

Comment: Yes, but those choice indexes are almost never important. The indexes are implicit in a list.

Answer (score 2):

When you set your choices, the list looks like `[(index, value),...]` so you don't need to import it, and probably shouldn't if setting dynamically

```
value = dict(form.hour.choices).get(form.hour.data)
```

Substitute self for form if inside form class

In general, I often zip the choices so index and value are the same. However, sometimes I want to present a displayed selection that's shorter than the value of interest. In that case, I think of it like `[(value, display),...]` and then the data variable *is* the value of interest. For example, `[(abspath, basename), ...]`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to get the index from form.hour.data and call it like this:

```
index = int(form.hour.data)
form.hour.choices[index][1]
```

Comment: More general solution would be to find the element itself:
`[c for c in form.hour.choices if c[0] == form.hour.data][0]`
and get the index then: `c[1]`.