# How to get value (not key) data from SelectField in WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a WTF SelectField, and I'm trying to store the name of the user's choice for display on another page.

Given that my form is

```
choice = SelectField('Choice', choices=[('cho_1', 'Choice One'), ('cho2', 'Choice Two')])
```

I understand that

```
self.choice = form.choice.data
```

will get me the user's choice (say, cho_1), but how do I get the *value* ("Choice One")? I feel like it's something simple with dicts, but various attempts plus googling/searching SO haven't helped so far.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to [Ashish Nitin Patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2689986/ashish-nitin-patil) for directing me to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217475/get-selected-text-from-a-form-using-wtforms-selectfield).

I needed to transform the 'choices' into a dict, then get the value for key form.data, thus:

```
 value = dict(form.choice.choices).get(form.choice.data)
```

Comment: Good solution! Case your keys are integers, depending on the use, you may need to do something like `value = dict(form.choice.choices).get(int(form.choice.data))`