# How to properly add column headers into WTForms dynamic selectfield list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a Pandas dataframe and trying to return the column headers into WTForm dynamic list on a Flask application.
However when I try to submit the HTML form, I get a validation error. Here is my form class error.

```
   data = pd.read_excel("sampledata.xlsx")
   col_headers = list(data.columns)

   col_list = list(col_headers)
   dic_list = {i : col_list[i] for i in range(0, len(col_list))}


   class StatementForm(FlaskForm):
   date = SelectField('Date', choices = [(key, dic_list[key]) for key in dic_list])
```

I have tested the HTML form by manually inputting a tuple in the choices list and it worked. Apparently the problem is in the 'date' parameter and the choices.

Your help in reviwing the code is most apreciated.

Comment: Try `str(key)` in your choices comprehension. In my experience the SelectField does not like integer keys.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of some steps by doing: `choices = [(str(x), y) for (x, y) in list(enumerate(data.columns))]` and do it all in one line. Let me know if this works

Comment: @snakecharmerb There is nothing much to show on the console, the validation rules stops the code from loading. Here is the screenshot
https://pasteboard.co/IfaeH7r.png

Comment: @WoodyPride it kind of worked because my form now displays the column header values and submits. However I noticed whenever the data is called it is the Key or index ID that is outputted.

       `form = StatementForm()`
       `date = form.date.data`

date returns an index number

Comment: @WoodyPride Please drop your comment as an answer so I can accept it.
I was able to resolve the outputted Index ID - This solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217475/get-selected-text-from-a-form-using-wtforms-selectfield worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following to create your choices:

```
choices = [(str(x), y) for (x, y) in list(enumerate(data.columns))]
```

The difference is that that value in the above code is a string. As per the WFT-Forms documentation:

> Select fields keep a choices property which is a sequence of (value, label) pairs. The value portion can be any type in theory, but as form data is sent by the browser as strings, you will need to provide a function which can coerce the string representation back to a comparable object.

In your version  you are trying to pass integers as the value, so that is why it is breaking.